# similarity as a percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently trying to find an Excel formula that will give me a percentage of words correct.

Example:

Cell A1: sit ubu sit good dog

Cell B1: sit obo sit good dog

Formula cell should reflect 80% correct or 0.80

Is there any way to do this?  The sentences I'm examining are up to 15 words long.

Comment: Are they always the same sentence?  E.g., obo dog sit sit good could be 80% or 20% correct.  Is A1 always the "correct" version and B1 what you are comparing to it?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to set up a "key" column and then a comparison column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach assuming you are working with supposedly identical sentences except for spelling.

```
    Select A1.  
    From the menu, select the Data tab, Text to Columns, and you will get a wizard.
    First screen, select Delimited, then Next.  
    Second screen, select Space, then Next.  
    Third screen, for the Destination put D1, then Finish.
```

This will put each word into a separate cell starting in D1.  Do the same sequence after selecting B1 except use D2 for the destination.  Now each word for the sentence in B1 will be under the corresponding word from A1.

In D3, enter this formula:

```
    =1*(D1=D2)-ISBLANK(D1)
```

Copy the formula across for 15 cells.  If the words match, it will produce 1, otherwise 0.  The ISBLANK leave the expression as 0 if the "matching words" are empty cells.

For the answer in C1, use this formula:

```
    =SUM(D3:R3)/COUNTA(D1:R1)
```

This will give you the number of matches divided by the number of word pairs.  Format the cell as a percentage.

Comment: you're a rock star....  I got it...  now I need to figure out how much time this takes versus what I was doing.... maybe if I copy the same sheet over again and take out the responses....